# unable to set arial font in mpdf 7.x

Tags: mpdf

followed the guide described here :
https://mpdf.github.io/fonts-languages/fonts-in-mpdf-7-x.html

```
    $defaultConfig = (new \Mpdf\Config\ConfigVariables())->getDefaults();
    $fontDirs = $defaultConfig['fontDir'];

    $defaultFontConfig = (new \Mpdf\Config\FontVariables())->getDefaults();
    $fontData = $defaultFontConfig['fontdata'];

    $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
        'fontDir' => array_merge($fontDirs, [__DIR__ . '/../../Resources/Public/Fonts',]),
        'fontdata' => $fontData + [
            'Arial' => [
                'R' => 'arial.ttf',
                'I' => 'arial.ttf',
            ]
        ],
        'default_font' => 'Arial'
    ]);

    $mpdf->WriteHTML($pdfTemplate->render());
    $mpdf->Output(__DIR__.'/document.pdf','F');
```

in template have also inline style with font-family

```
font-family: Arial, sans-serif
```

but when i download pdf and inspect fonts they are in default DejaVuSansCondensed

is it bug or did i make mistake somewhere ?

Comment: I have the same problem currently using the arial font found here:https://github.com/JotJunior/PHP-Boleto-ZF2/blob/master/public/assets/fonts/arial.ttf - Could you solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

long time ago, but i have the same problem.
solution was the uppcase key in "fontdata" (Arial). this should be lowercase (arial) and in css use: "font-family: arial, other-fallback-font"